# TypeError: e is not a function | Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

After changing the `production` property to `true` in environment I receive `TypeError: e is not a function`. It happens only when I try to access specific route, eg. `www.example.com` works, `www.example.com/member` doesn't. This error occurs both on normal and lazy loaded modules. With `production` set to `false` everything works fine.

Error occurs in main.js, we can clearly see the error as `e is not a function`:

```
function D() {
            for (var t = [], e = 0; e < arguments.length; e++)
                t[e] = arguments[e];
            return function(e) {
                if (0 === t.length)
                    return e;
                var n = t[t.length - 1];
                return t.slice(0, -1).reduceRight(function(t, e) {
                    return e(t)
                }, n(e))
            }
        }
```

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.29",
    "amazing-time-picker": "^1.5.3",
    "auth0-js": "^9.7.3",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "css-reset-and-normalize-sass": "^0.1.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^2.8.4",
    "ngx-tui-calendar": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

I believe that there is something wrong with minification. I built the app with `ng build --prod`. Typescript version is `3.1.6`.

Comment: Why u dont use TypeScript v 3.3.3?

Comment: Didn't update this and that's all, no specific reason.

Comment: Then try to use it...

Comment: @MassiveCodes Angular compiler requires version <3.3

Comment: LuL? Nope working here at work too whit angular and ts 3.3.3

Comment: @MassiveCodes I receive `ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.3.0 but 3.3.3 was found instead.` with `@angular/core` at version `7.2.4`. Currently I updated typescript from 3.1.6 to 3.2.4

Comment: are you tried to update all dependencys? `ng update --all --force`